# How to run main project with all sub-project in scala SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using multi-project build in SBT to create a simple microservice architecture. I defined build.sbt as:

```
addCommandAlias("rebuild", ";clean; compile; package")

lazy val oc = Project(id = "oc",
  base = file("."),
  settings = commonSettings).aggregate(
  persistence,
  core,
  configuration,
  integration).dependsOn(
  persistence,
  core,
  configuration,
  integration)
  .configs (MultiJvm)

lazy val persistence = Project(...)

lazy val core = Project(...)

lazy val log = Project(...)

lazy val configuration = Project(...)

lazy val integration = Project(...)

lazy val commonSettings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++
  basicSettings ++
  net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings

lazy val basicSettings = Seq(
  version := PROJECT_VERSION,
  organization := ORGANIZATION,
  scalaVersion := SCALA_VERSION,

  scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-feature", "-unchecked", "-Xlog-reflective-calls", "-Xlint" , "-encoding", "utf8"),
  javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation"),
  javaOptions in run ++= Seq("-Xms128m", "-Xmx1024m"),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq( ...
  ),
  fork in run := true,
  // disable parallel tests
  parallelExecution in Test := false,
  licenses := Seq(("CC0", url("http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0"))),
  fork in Test := true
)
```

For single sub-project I can easily build the project. But I cannot build all projects at once to check the working as a whole system. Any help from the experts on building the system would be appreciable

Comment: When you say "build all the projects", do you mean compile them? Or do you have one root project that depends on other parts?

Comment: Because it _looks_ like you just need to set `mainClass` in `oc`'s settings.

Comment: Root Project is dependent on other projects. I wanted to compile all sub-projects and run when `sbt run` command is executed

Comment: Also @erip, if you could help me find the best resources to learn building Microservices(muti sub-projects) using Scala and Akka, I would really appreciate it

Comment: Consider using Lagom.

Comment: I would like to learn from the Scratch building the Microservices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156097/discussion-between-sujit-and-erip).